# Can we change font color of the data in td tag of html using only CSS

Tags: html, css, jenkins, css-selectors, jenkins-email-ext

I am creating a custom report that is inserted inside a body of an email content in the form of html. My report generates a table with 3 rows and multiple columns. In 1 of the columns  the value is determined dynamically via an environment variable (something like this: $CHILD2_BUILD_RESULT) in Jenkins (either SUCCESS or FAILURE). I want to change the font color of this text placed inside  depending on the value. Green if it is SUCCESS , Red if it is FAILURE.

My current code (below) is hard-coded and displays green irrespective of the status.

Is this possible just by using CSS or CSS conditional formatting or handlebars without jquery or javascript

```
<tr>
  <td>Test Result</td>
  <td style="color: green;"> <strong>$CHILD1_BUILD_RESULT </strong> </td>
  <td style="color: green;"> <strong>$CHILD2_BUILD_RESULT </strong> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: how, exactly, are the environment variables being replaced with actual values before sending the email out? it might help to see the relevant portion of your jenkins build configuration.

Comment: $CHILD1_BUILD_RESULT and $CHILD2_BUILD_RESULT are default environment variables generated by Jenkins build based on their jobs. I have two multi-jobs CHILD1 and CHILD2. Jenkins generated the above mentioned environment variables which returns the status of the job i.e., SUCCESS or FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the rendered HTML is going into an email is knee-capping you a bit here. There are lots of neat tricks you could do with selectors, but emails require that all CSS be inlined -- which means no selectors.

Your best option is to modify the process that builds the final email output and define two new environment variables: `CHILD1_BUILD_RESULT_COLOR` and `CHILD2_BUILD_RESULT_COLOR`. These would contain the string values "green" or "red" (depending on the value of `CHILD1_BUILD_RESULT` and `CHILD2_BUILD_RESULT`).

I know you were probably hoping for a more elegant solution, but CSS in email is very limited and has always been a pain point for designers and developers.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your suggestion? CHILD1_BUILD_RESULT & CHILD2_BUILD_RESULTare the default environment variables generated by Jenkins that store the result of their respective jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution by adding a class to the  tag. I named the class as the jenkins environment variable that would store wither SUCCESS or FAILURE then I styles 2 .SUCCESS & .FAILURE as needed inline. This could display the output they I wanted to in email.